# Express as a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let the universal set $U$ be the set of all people, let $M$ bet the set of all males, let $C$ be the set of all children, let $H$ be the set of all dutch people.

Express as sets:

a) boys

b) girls

c) adult women

d) adult dutch men

e) non-dutch girls

Not sure how to express something as a set? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is the set of all Dutch people labeled $H$? Shouldn't it be $N$? :)

Comment: @5xum $H$ as in Holland, probably.

Comment: @naslundx That's my point, not all Dutch people live in Holland, some live in other parts of the Netherlands... :)

Comment: Folks from e.g. Friesland will indeed dislike the notation.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that when you're looking for overlapping elements of two groups, you're looking for their intersection.  This is a big upside down U in set notation.  An apostrophe signifies a "not".  So answer a here essentially says, "every element of the men group that is also in the children group".

a) $M \cap C$

b) $M' \cap C$

c) $M' \cap C'$

d) $C' \cap H \cap M$

e) $M' \cap C \cap H'$

Comment: This is a very bad answer. It does not help the OP to understand the things that are confusing him and is also very badly formatted.

Comment: I apologize, I have forgotten the code for an intersection.  Will fix ASAP.

Comment: I fixed your formatting. `\bigcap` is an operator you use like the `\sum` operator. I also still think your answer is bad as it does not help OP to understand anything, you just gave him the answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Just the first two:

1. The set of all boys is the set of all people who are children and are males.
   Therefore, a person is in the set of boys if and only if the person is in the set of children **and** the person is in the set of males. Which set operation is connected with the **and** logical operator?
2. The set of all girls is the set of all people who are children and are not males. A person is in the set of girls if and only if the person is in the set of children and is **not** in the set of boys. Which set operation is connected to the **not** operator?

Comment: Ah, i forgot unions and intersections existed -_- So AND is intersection, but what is NOT? (Union?)

Comment: @Jamboo An element is in $A\cup B$ if it is in $A$ **or** if it is in $B$. There is, however, a name for a set $C$ with the property: $x$ is in $C$ if and only if it is **not** in $A$.